# Converting to 2NF, then 3NF showing both conversions

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

I am struggling to figure out how to find both conversions to this problem. I am trying to learn database design / database normalization before I jump into creating my first database.

For example: I am trying to convert the following to 2NF, and then 3NF showing both conversions. I am stuck on the 'both conversions' part.

(b, m, i, o, d, j, l, s, e, c, n, h, a, f, k, p, r, g)

The FD's:
b → f               m → k           b → e
m → l               m → a           i → c
n, h → p            l → a           l → k
r → g               o → s

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normalization to 3NF should not be done via 2NF, it can prevent you from getting the best 3NF designs.

Comment: So what is your reference material and what does is say to do first?

Answer (score 2):

If you are taking a course, then follow your teacher's plan first, before taking advice from others.  But if you are learning on your own, here are a few tips.

One thing to realize is that normalization is a bottom up approach, and not a top down approach.  Where it's most useful is when you are given a body of data that is already defined, and you want to know how normalized it is.  In the early days of relational databases, there were plenty of systems being cut over from paper based manual systems, or from file and record systems, or from prerelational DBMSes.  Normalization could help you understand that data better, and give you a real good handle on why the existing system wasn't working very well.

But if you want a top down approach, I suggest a completely different plan.  Learn how to to ER modeling of the subject matter itself.  Don't try to design a database with an ER model.  That is not its strength.  Instead, try to understand how the subject matter experts understand their data.  ER modeling is simple, but it's abstract.  The hard part about ER modeling is making sure that each attribute really describes the entity or relationship you are attaching it to.  It's very easy to get this wrong.

Once you have a good ER model, and one that passes the reality test, convert it to a relational model.  This is where you convert the entities and relationships into tables, and the attributes into columns, and put in foreign keys.  If you do this fairly mechanically,  you should end up in 3NF, most of the time.  No gurantees about efficiency, however.

Now, as you begin tweaking this model for better performance, keep track of what you are doing to make sure that the only denormalization you perform is intentional.  There are plenty of cases where a somewhat denormalized database works "better" than a normalized one, although it's easy to go wrong.

The more you do it, the better you'll get.

Comment: Can you really be so confident that an ER model converted "mechanically" into tables will result in a database design that satisfies 3NF? That would have to depend on how well your analysis process identified the functional dependencies and captured them in your ER model. ER modelling practice has *no* standard way to represent FDs in general and it is relatively unusual in my experience even to see ER models that define alternate keys. These are just two reasons why I would not rely on ER modelling to produce a normalized database design.

Comment: I did say, "most of the time".  This is a rule of thumb, not a formal foolproof methodology.  However, if the identifiers for the entitiies are chosen well, all of the other attributes will be dependent on the indentifier, the entire identifier, and nothing but the identifier, most of the time.  Try it a few times, and see how well it works.  You might cirticize my advising a newbie to rely on a heuristic, but I'm trying to keep things simple.

Comment: BTW, you are right to point out that FD's are not part of the ER model.  That's why I think that people who come in and ask whether their ERD is normalized may need to clarify in their own heads whether they are doing ER modeling or relational modeling.

Comment: The OP didn't mention ERD. You introduced the topic.

Answer (score 1):

According to your FD's and Relation , your Candidate key will be: {bmiodjnhr}

Hence ,

```
    Prime Attrbutes (9) ={b,m,i,o,d,j,n,h,r}

    Non-Prime Attrbutes (9) = { l, s, e, c, a, f, k, p, g}





                     Now Checking for 2NF:
```

"Partial Dependencies are not allowed". Means part of Candidate key should not determine the Non- Prime Attribute.

Here Partial Dependencies are:

b → f 
m → k
b → e
m → l 
m → a
i → c
n, h → p 
r → g 
o → s

```
             Hence Partial Dependencies exist, Relation is not in 2NF.

                  *How to resolve Partial Dependencies*
```

Decompose your relation like this:

R1= {bfe}

R2= {mkla}

R3= {ic}

R4= {nhp}

R5= {rg}

R6= {os}

R7= {bmiodjnr}

```
                   Now Checking for 3NF:
```

"Transitive Dependencies are not allowed in 3NF"

Means,
Your Database is in 3NF if and only if it follow any one or both of below rules:

Rule 1 : For Each given FD's , Left Hand Side(LHS) of FD should be Superkey for any table in Database.

OR

Rule 2 : For Each given FD's , Right Hand Side (RHS) of FD should be Prime Attribute for the ant Relation / Table.

Here Transitive Dependency is : l → a , l → k

Hence Transitive Dependencies exist, Relation is not in 3NF.

```
             *How to resolve Transitive Dependencies*
```

Decompose your table like this:

R1= {bfe}

R2= {ml}

R3= {lak}

R4= {ic}

R5= {nhp}

R6= {rg}

R7= {os}

R8= {bmiodjnr}

```
                            **Now this is in 3NF.**
```

Hope it helps.
This is the Answer of your question. If you want to learn exactly how to check if a relation is in 2NF or 3NF or BCNF or how find a candidate key or how to decompose a table , Please refer "Normalization" section of my notes. Here is the link : [DataBase Normalization](http://ashishparihargatenotes.blogspot.in/2016/03/database-management-system-best-one.html)